# The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, build, react-native-ios

**Whenever I tries to do `pod install` it gives me this error**

> Downloading dependencies
>  Installing BVLinearGradient (2.5.6)
> Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.5)
>  Installing DoubleConversion
> (1.1.6)
>  Installing FBLazyVector (0.64.0)
>  Installing
> FBReactNativeSpec (0.64.0)
>  Installing Flipper (0.75.1)
> Installing Flipper-Boost-iOSX (1.76.0.1.11)
>  Installing
> Flipper-DoubleConversion (1.1.7)
>  Installing Flipper-Fmt
> (7.1.7)
>  Installing Flipper-Folly (2.6.9)
>  Installing
> Flipper-Glog (0.3.6)
>  Installing Flipper-PeerTalk (0.0.4)
> Installing Flipper-RSocket (1.4.3)
>  Installing FlipperKit
> (0.75.1)
>  Installing GoogleMaps (3.1.0)
>  Installing
> GooglePlaces (3.1.0)
>  Installing JGProgressHUD (2.2)
> Installing MDFInternationalization (2.0.0)
>  Installing
> MaterialComponents (124.2.0)
>  Installing MotionAnimator
> (4.0.1)
>  Installing MotionInterchange (3.0.0)
>  Installing
> OpenSSL-Universal (1.1.1100)
>  Installing Pulsator (0.6.0)
> Installing RCT-Folly (2020.01.13.00)
>  Installing RCTRequired
> (0.64.0)
>  Installing RCTTypeSafety (0.64.0)
>  Installing
> RNCAsyncStorage (1.15.2)
>  Installing RNCCheckbox (0.5.7)
> Installing RNDeviceInfo (8.1.2)
>  Installing RNGestureHandler
> (1.10.3)
>  Installing RNImageCropPicker (0.36.0)
>  Installing
> RNReanimated (2.1.0)
>  Installing RNSVG (12.1.1)
>  Installing
> RNScreens (3.1.1)
>  Installing RNVectorIcons (8.1.0)
> Installing React (0.64.0)
>  Installing React-Core (0.64.0)
> Installing React-CoreModules (0.64.0)
>  Installing
> React-RCTActionSheet (0.64.0)
>  Installing React-RCTAnimation
> (0.64.0)
>  Installing React-RCTBlob (0.64.0)
>  Installing
> React-RCTImage (0.64.0)
>  Installing React-RCTLinking (0.64.0)
> Installing React-RCTNetwork (0.64.0)
>  Installing React-RCTSettings
> (0.64.0)
>  Installing React-RCTText (0.64.0)
>  Installing
> React-RCTVibration (0.64.0)
>  Installing React-callinvoker
> (0.64.0)
>  Installing React-cxxreact (0.64.0)
>  Installing
> React-jsi (0.64.0)
>  Installing React-jsiexecutor (0.64.0)
> Installing React-jsinspector (0.64.0)
>  Installing React-perflogger
> (0.64.0)
>  Installing React-runtimeexecutor (0.64.0)
> Installing ReactCommon (0.64.0)
>  Installing ReactNativeART
> (1.2.0)
>  Installing ReactNativeLocalization (2.1.6)
> Installing TOCropViewController (2.6.0)
>  Installing Yoga
> (1.14.0)
>  Installing YogaKit (1.18.1)
>  Installing
> ZIPFoundation (0.9.11)
>  Installing boost-for-react-native
> (1.63.0)
>  Installing glog (0.3.5)
>  Installing iDenfySDK
> (6.3.0)
>  Installing idenfy-react-native-sdk (1.6.0)
> Installing libevent (2.1.12)
>  Installing lottie-ios (3.2.3)
> Installing react-native-google-places (3.1.2)
>  Installing
> react-native-image-picker (3.3.2)
>  Installing
> react-native-image-resizer (1.4.4)
>  Installing react-native-maps
> (0.27.1)
>
> > The Swift pod `iDenfySDK` depends upon `MaterialComponents` and
> > `JGProgressHUD`, which do not define modules. To opt into those
> > targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from
> > Swift when building as static libraries), you may set
> > `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify
> > `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

**If anyone know how to solve this issue**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't it tell you already how to solve the issue?

> To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set use_modular_headers! globally in your Podfile, or specify :modular_headers => true for particular dependencies.

Comment: yes it did! but actually I'm new on Mac OS and don't know how to use `use_modular_headers`, so that's why I'm having problem at this stage . ill be grateful if you help me  thanks:)

Comment: You just add `use_modular_headers!` to your Podfile I assume. (And then do a `pod install` again)

Answer (score 9):

Add this top of the pod file.

use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

Comment: it works but what does it mean to add :linkage => :static

Comment: worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"**use_frameworks! :linkage => :static**"
It is used to configure CocoaPods to use statically linked frameworks instead of dynamically linked frameworks. By default, CocoaPods uses dynamic frameworks. You can change it from XCode too. [image]